# Modificar archivos generados por CRUD de Scaffold

Tags: c#, mvc, asp

Buenas noches quisiera saber ¿Cómo tengo que modificar el template .t4 del controller? o lo que tenga que cambiar para poder generar los archivos con Scaffold con el nombre personalizado.

- El archivo con el nombre Create.cshtml se cree con el nombre Crear.cshtml
- El archivo con el nombre Delete.cshtml se cree con el nombre Eliminar.cshtml
- El archivo con el nombre Details.cshtml se cree con el nombre Detalles.cshtml
- El archivo con el nombre Edit.cshtml se cree con el nombre Editar.cshtml
- Este puede mantener el mismo nombre Index.cshtml -> Index.cshtml

Modificando el template del controller logré cambiar los métodos de acción que me crea automáticamente el **Scaffold**:

```
    // GET: Cuentas
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Cuentas.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Cuentas/Details/5
    public ActionResult Detalles(string id)
    {
        //Codigo Autogenerado
        return View(cuenta);
    }

    // GET: Cuentas/Create
    public ActionResult Crear()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Eso esta bien, pero como dije: no se cómo generar los archivos CRUD con los nombre que yo quiero, gracias.

Comment: No esta muy claro tu problema, lo que queres es que `public ActionResult Crear()` te envíe a otro archivo `cshtml` en lugar de `Crear.cshtml`?

Comment: Lo que deseo es que el scaffold que genera tanto el controller como las vistas me genere las vistas con esos nombre, por ejemplo crea automaticamente el archivo "Create.cshtml" y yo quiero que cree "Crear.cshtml"

Comment: No lo puedes "configurar", los debes cambiar a mano.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias pensé que se podía cambiar usando los templates .t4 o algo asi.